# Why does 32 bit reference sectors and not bytes for MBR hard disks?

Tags: hard-drive, mbr

Trying to educate myself on hard disk architecture and I am trying to wrap my head around the concept of the 2TB limitation for MBR. The question that arose is why 2^32 related to sectors and not bits? Why are there 4294967296 sectors? I apologize if my question seems a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

Data is read in blocks (sector)  of 512 bytes (or larger for more drives) - thus you get 4,294,967,296 / 2 kbytes of data = 2.2tb - the limitation of addressing for MBR disks.

I'm not entirely sure of the intricacies, but the larger the sector size, the more efficient the drive - almost certainly due in part to caching and buffers.

From the other extreme -

It makes no sense at all to read bits of a drive - the smallest "sensible" unit which can be represented is 8 bits = 1 byte.  Even this is to small to be of much use - and as the hard drive is spinning it may as well grab a reasonable chunk of information as it passes under the head, instead of waiting for it to fly past again.

Comment: Where did you get the number of 2kb

Comment: That formatted badly. It was actually / 2 (to go from 512k sectors to 1024 byte blocks) is the size of the disk in kb.